# Unable to locate application file Setup.msi after creating c# application + install wizard

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

I've created a application using C#. Now I've tried to create a Setup Wizard for this application.

I build the application after finishing the setup wizard, now I've went to my Debug folder and I tried to execute the installer but received the following error:

**Error:**

Unable to locate application file 'Infinite Trainer Setup.msi'.

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\d4ne\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDF9F.tmp\install.log' for more information.

**Install.log:**

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 10.0.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read string value '4.6.01586'
Setting value '4.6.01586 {string}' for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_TargetVersion] = 4.6.01586 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.5.50709': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
Error: Unable to locate application file 'Infinite Trainer Setup.msi'.
```

**How the install wizard was created:**

1. Right click on Solution 'InfiniteTrainer'
2. Add new Project -> Other Project Types -> Setup Wizard
3. Clicked the next button
4. Marked 'Create a setup for Windows applications'
5. Clicked the next button
6. Marked every checkbox as you can see in the screenshot:
7. Clicked the finish button

[image]

Does anyone have a idea what I did wrong? I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: The `msi` file *is* the installer. That's the only thing you need to distribute. Did you copy only the `setup.exe` perhaps? That's just the bootstrapper, it installs any missing dependencies before the actual installation starts

Comment: It happens once I click the .exe as you can see in the following screenshot https://gyazo.com/618079e71a109c9fa7ac7d0096ff2ce7

Comment: As I said, the `exe` is *not* the installer, it's just the bootstrapper. You don't really need it to install the application.

Comment: Where do I find the installer then? Sorry, never really created a installer

Comment: after your project is successfully compiled, you should see two files. .msi and .exe. see the screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/RRtS8QV.jpg

Comment: by default setup project is not selected for compilation so make sure that Build is checked for setup project as shown on this screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/pCNKuQd.jpg